# Capistrano deployment when db is not same machine as web server

Tags: deployment, capistrano, setup-deployment

From what I understand by default code will be deployed too all roles defined. Let's say you have a db on a different machine then your web server. You define roles for both the web server and the db then deploy. Currently my capistrano script is deploying the source to both machines. I want it to deploy source only to the web server.

How can this be done? The capistrano site mostly has examples of single machine architectures.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you'll need the code on the db machine to run migrations and what-not, won't you?

Comment: ah right, bad example I guess. I wasn't actually taking about a db (that was just my example) I was actually talking about a config for a load balancer which does sit in a repository. guess what I actually want is just the copying of the config which i know how to do. sorry again dumb question. :P

Comment: You can always define new roles, assign servers per role and define tasks to be run only in defined role ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have separate web and app servers. In order to not deploy the code to the web server, I use the following:

```
role :web, "myappserver.com", :no_release => true
```

Many of the tasks in capistrano are qualified to not run when this variable is set.